# Saved data on Android seems not available after installing a new version of my app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I save some settings and progress of my Android app (built with Unity) in files I save at the persistent data path of the device. After installing a newer version of the app it seems that all the values are reset which means the old saved file has not been found.

Here is my code to save and load:

```
public void save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + saveFilename);

    //initialize and give some data
    SaveData data = new SaveData(autoMove, hideControls, playMusic, joystickSize);

    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
}

public void load()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + saveFilename))
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + saveFilename, FileMode.Open);

            SaveData data = bf.Deserialize(file) as SaveData;

            //get data here
            autoMove = data.autoMove;
            hideControls = data.hideControls;
            playMusic = data.playMusic;
            joystickSize = data.joystickSize;

            file.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //could debug here
        }
    }
}

//default values
[HideInInspector] public bool autoMove = false;
[HideInInspector] public bool hideControls = false;
[HideInInspector] public bool playMusic = true;
[HideInInspector] public int joystickSize = 1;

[Serializable]
public class SaveData
{
    //put in data here
    public bool autoMove;
    public bool hideControls;
    public bool playMusic;
    public int joystickSize;

    public SaveData(bool autoMove, bool hideControls, bool playMusic, int joystickSize)
    {
        this.autoMove = autoMove;
        this.hideControls = hideControls;
        this.playMusic = playMusic;
        this.joystickSize = joystickSize;
    }
}
```

The saveFilename is always the same of course. Why do I have problems to load my old save after updating the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one of the reasons why `BinaryFormatter`  should **not** be used to save your player data in Unity.There is a possibility you will lose those data after making an update.

From my experiment few years ago, data loss with `BinaryFormatter` *usually* happens when you **add** or **remove** new variables in your old class then after update, you try to read and deserialize the saved value to the new updated class. There could be other reasons too.

This problem is almost impossible to happen when using `Json` or `Xml` with `PlayerPrefs` to save your game data. I haven't seen a case where this happens when `Json` and `PlayerPrefs` is used to save your game data, so that's what you should be using.

Your new save and load functions should look like something below:

```
public void save()
{
    //initialize and give some data
    SaveData data = new SaveData(autoMove, hideControls, playMusic, joystickSize);
    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("playerData", jsonData);
}

public void load()
{
    string jsonData = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerData");
    SaveData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(jsonData);

    //get data here
    autoMove = data.autoMove;
    hideControls = data.hideControls;
    playMusic = data.playMusic;
    joystickSize = data.joystickSize;
}
```

Make sure to up `[System.Serializable]` on top of each class you which to save data with or else, `JsonUtility` will fail. It is up to you to add encryption before saving the data.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not add or delete variables in the new version by the way but could not read them.

Comment: @Tobias Maybe Unity is doing something else to it. You should not use `BinaryFormatter` for this.  Don't forget to accept this answer if the code above solved your problem.

Comment: Just did it I am new to this forum. Just one more thing don't I need to save the json data or is it automatically saved? with JsonUtility.ToJson?

Comment: `JsonUtility.ToJson` will convert the data in your class to Json(string) which is in human readable format. You can use `Debug.Log(jsonData)` to see what the converted json data looks like. `JsonUtility.ToJson`  does **not** save the data. It only converts it to json. `PlayerPrefs.SetString` is then used to save the json data. Google `PlayerPrefs.SetString` to learn how it works.

Comment: Very nice now I am a lot smarter than before! Thank you!

Comment: I found out what caused my issue: When uninstalling the app all save data is deleted, but while updating it stays on it's place. My problem was caused by marking the build as a development build which changes the persistent data path somehow as I read in another forum post. I guess when changing to a development build, the original apk is even uninstalled normally so that all data is lost. My users can keep their data now because they only use normal updates, the BinaryFormatter works fine!

Comment: It's good to know that. What I said about problems that occur when the class is modified is still true. Also, if you can, use `PlayerPrefs`. Here is another person having that problem and got almost the-same [answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1169350/view.html).